# map column values with other table column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have on column rais_date in one table in let test and i want to map this column with it's transaction table column let rais_trans_date. in mysql is it is possible.

Means all the value of rais_date automatically copy to rais_trans_date, either add or update in master table column i.e. rais_date.

if yes please suggest me how..

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySql Triggers to do this...

CREATE TRIGGER `` ` BEFORE INSERT ON ``TableName` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

-- Your Logic Goes here

END

Comment: I want to update same table after inserting record in table that is not allowed by trigger. as per mySQL documentation.
Any other solution.